# is it possible to overlay two images which share landmarks but different details using opencv matching algorithm

Tags: python, opencv

I am using the following code to overlay images taken using different microscopy. The two images describe the same tissue but with different techniques.

```
def match_images_using_orb(em_image, confocal_image): 

    gray_confocal = cv2.cvtColor(confocal_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    #em_image is already gray

    orb = cv2.ORB_create(500) 
    keypoints1, descriptors1 = orb.detectAndCompute(em_image, None) 
    keypoints2, descriptors2 = orb.detectAndCompute(gray_confocal, None)

    #brute force matcher
    matcher = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING)
    matches = matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2) 

    matches.sort(key = lambda x: x.distance, reverse = False)
    top_matches = int(len(matches) * 0.1)
    matches = matches[:top_matches]
    imMatches = cv2.drawMatches(em_image, keypoints1, gray_confocal, keypoints2, matches, None)

    points1 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype = np.float32)
    points2 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype = np.float32)

    for i, match in enumerate(matches): 
        points1[i, :] = keypoints1[match.queryIdx].pt
        points2[i, :] = keypoints2[match.trainIdx].pt


    h, _ = cv2.findHomography(points1, points2, cv2.RANSAC)

    height, width, _ = em_image.shape 

    try:
        #exclude negative homography
        if h[ h < 0].size == 0:
            em_reg = cv2.warpPerspective(confocal_image, h, (width, height))
        else:
            return False 
    except: 
        return False
    else:
        return (imMatches, em_reg,  h)
```

Since the two images are different but they share common marks, using this algorithm might not be right.

My target is to know where is the green color and red color located in the larger image. To do so, I need to rotate the the image according to homography depending on some land marks as shown in below image(just an example)

So my question is; if I already know some landmarks like the blue color in both of the two images (blue color) how to feed the  homography of these landmarks to algorithm manually to rotate the small image in the write position so I can know where is green and red colors located (unknown).

[image]

Comment: How many landmarks do you have? How do the distributed across the image? Are they predefined or depend on the image?
In general - to compute homography you need at least 4 pairs of corresponding points.

Comment: Yes, I can select image pairs which share more than 4 landmarks. but even though this process need automation for cross matching of many images, since images are taken at different time points, so landmarks are same but they migrate

Comment: How do you find your landmarks? If you can get 4 corresponding pairs, you can compute homography as in your example. 
points1 - your landmarks from  image1
points2 - your landmarks from image 2
h, _ = cv2.findHomography(points1, points2)

Without the exemplary images its hard to understand whether your question is related to the way how to extract these points or how to match them.